# Possible to edit macOS Installer options through Terminal?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, startup, monterey

I have an Apple computer stuck on the latest OS (Monterey) update with just the progress bar and Apple logo. The installer logger shows the following errors:

> MacBook-Pro osinstallersetup(447): IFJS: Package Authoring Error:
> access to path "/tmp/com.apple.pkg.testing" requires <options
> allow-external-scripts='true`>
>
> MacBook-Pro osinstallersetup(447): IFJS: Package Authoring Error:
> access to path
> "/tmp/com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress"
> requires <options allow-external-scripts='true`>

The only interface I can access is Terminal through Recovery Boot. Is there a way to enable the `allow-external-scripts` option through Terminal to remedy this error?

Comment: Where'd you get the installer you're using?  Seems like it'd be far easier to just wipe the drive and begin again.

Comment: @MarcWilson I'm trying to avoid that if I can. This is not a third-party installer, it's Apple's. The OS update was attempted through System Preferences.

Comment: Another "I did an update without a backup", huh?